# Is there a way to format only some special characters with JSoup?

Tags: java, html, string, jsoup

Using the [JSoup library](https://jsoup.org) is there a way to only clean up some characters. For example I want `&nbsp;` to be replaced by spaces, and `&quot;` by an actual quote but I don't want any `<br>`, `<p>`, etc. to be removed or replaced. I don't want to extract all the html as it does with:

```
Jsoup.parse(html).text()
```

Instead what I want to do is provide it with a list, possibly an array, of encodings I want to be parsed and cleaned up such as `&quot;` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup does provide [`cleaning methods`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html). However, they can remove only elements or attributes.

Instead you can explore the elements text and make the replacements here.

Try this:

```
public static void formatDocument(Document doc, String[] encodings, String[] replacements) {
   // FIXME: Check that encodings and replacements have same size...

   Elements allElements = doc.select("*");
   int encodingsCount = encodings.length;

     for(Element anElement : allElements) {
         String textElement = anElement.ownText();

         for(int i=0; i<encodingsCount; i++) {
             textElement = textElement.replace(encodings[i], replacements[i]);
         }

         anElement.text(textElemement);
     }
}
```

#### See also:

[How do I build a NodeTraversor/NodeVisitor with JSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37224652/363573)